# Why does the order of including modules make a difference in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, include, module

This question is best summed up with a code example:

```
module TestOne
  module Foo
    def foo
      42
    end
  end

  module Bar
    include Foo
  end

  class Quux
    include Bar
  end
end

TestOne::Bar.ancestors # => [TestOne::Bar, TestOne::Foo]
TestOne::Quux.ancestors # => [TestOne::Quux, TestOne::Bar, TestOne::Foo, Object, Kernel]
TestOne::Quux.new.foo # => 42

module TestTwo
  class Quux
  end

  module Bar
  end

  module Foo
    def foo
      42
    end
  end
end

TestTwo::Quux.send :include, TestTwo::Bar
TestTwo::Bar.send :include, TestTwo::Foo

TestTwo::Bar.ancestors # => [TestTwo::Bar, TestTwo::Foo]
TestTwo::Quux.ancestors # => [TestTwo::Quux, TestTwo::Bar, Object, Kernel]
TestTwo::Quux.new.foo # => 
# ~> -:40: undefined method `foo' for #<TestTwo::Quux:0x24054> (NoMethodError)
```

I thought that when you include a module (e.g. `Bar` inside a class `Foo`) all that Ruby stores is the fact that `Foo` includes `Bar`. So, when you call a method on Foo it looks in `Bar` for the method.

If that was true, by the time `TestTwo::Quux.new.foo` is called I've mixed the `foo` method into `TestTwo::Bar` so it should work, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs say that [append_features](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001659) (which is called by include) mixes the methods into the caller. So when `TestTwo::Quux` includes `TestTwo::Bar`, no methods are added to `TestTwo::Quux`. The next line adds methods to `TestTwo::Bar`, but not to `TestTwo::Quux`.

Comment: That's a shame because in my real case the first include happens out of my control, I'm just trying to mix something into anything which includes my target module. Ah well, thanks :)